# MYSQL multiple WHERE IN causes LIKE to be ignored(?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that doesn't work. I've fixed the problem by using a single IN statement (the library I'm using to construct my queries was causing this to happen) but I'm still curious *why* this happens.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) 
WHERE     `field` = 'false' 
      AND `something` LIKE '%string%' 
      AND `status_id` IN ('1') 
      OR `status_id` IN ('2') 
      OR `status_id` IN ('3')
```

The query to me makes sense: Select everything from the table where field = false and something is like string and status id is in 1 or status id is in 2 or status id is in 3

When there are multiple IN statements the LIKE portion of the query is completely ignored.

Any ideas why mutliple IN statements would cause the LIKE to be ignored? I can't work out why: re-arranging the query has no affect (moving the LIKE to the end vs. the start)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precendence? Shouldn't you use brackets to differentiate the AND and OR? `status_id` IN ('x') will if true cause the rest of the expression to be ignored.

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) 
WHERE     `field` = 'false' 
      AND `something` LIKE '%string%' 
      AND (`status_id` IN ('1') 
            OR `status_id` IN ('2') 
            OR `status_id` IN ('3') 
      )
```

which is the same as

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) 
WHERE     `field` = 'false' 
      AND `something` LIKE '%string%' 
      AND `status_id` IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Try it for yourself by seeing what comes out with this.

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) 
WHERE     `field` = 'false' 
      AND `something` LIKE '%string%' 
      AND `status_id` IN ('1') 
      OR 1=1
```

Ask yourself what this query should return

Answer (score 1):

In most languages, including MySQL, the `and` operator binds more tightly than `or`. Therefore your code means

```
WHERE ( field = 'false' AND something LIKE '%string%' AND status_id IN ('1') )
OR status_id IN ('2') 
OR status_id IN ('3')
```

The fix is clearly to use parentheses around the three `IN` conditions:

```
WHERE field = 'false'
AND something LIKE '%string%'
AND ( status_id IN ('1') OR status_id IN ('2')  OR status_id IN ('3') )
```